# How to encrypt string using openpgp.js?

Tags: javascript, encryption, public-key-encryption, openpgp.js

I am trying to use the Encrypt and decrypt String data with PGP keys example from openpgp.js but I struggle to make it work inside Firefox. [openpgp.js doc](https://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/doc/#bower)

I create a keypair.

```
const openpgp = window.openpgp; // use as CommonJS, AMD, ES6 module or via window.openpgp

 openpgp.config.compression = openpgp.enums.compression.zlib

var options = {
 userIds: [{ name: 'Alicee', email:     'alice@example.com' }],
  numBits: 2048,
  passphrase: 'secretttoo'
};

var publicKeyAlice;
var privateKeyAlice;

 openpgp.generateKey(options).then(key     => {
privateKeyAlice = key.privateKeyArmored;
publicKeyAlice = key.publicKeyArmored;
console.log('Key generated');
console.log(privateKeyAlice);
 console.log(publicKeyAlice);

});
```

The keys I get consoled out are used for the example of string encryption by openpgp.js

```
const pubkey = '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- Version: OpenPGP.js v4.1.1'
const privkey = '-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK----- Version: OpenPGP.js v4.1.1'
const passphrase = `secretttoo` //what the privKey is encrypted with


const encryptDecryptFunction = async() => {
const privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey)).keys[0]
await privKeyObj.decrypt(passphrase)

const options = {
    message: openpgp.message.fromText('Hello, World!'),       // input as Message object
    publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for encryption
    privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                                 // for signing (optional)
}

openpgp.encrypt(options).then(ciphertext => {
    encrypted = ciphertext.data // '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE ... END PGP MESSAGE-----'
    return encrypted
})
.then(encrypted => {
    const options = {
        message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),    // parse armored message
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for verification (optional)
        privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                                 // for decryption
    }

    openpgp.decrypt(options).then(plaintext => {
        console.log(plaintext.data)
        return plaintext.data // 'Hello, World!'
    })

 })
}

encryptDecryptFunction();
```

I get the following error in browser console:

`SyntaxError: missing } after property list[Learn More] openpgp testing.html:153:27 note: { opened at line 152, column 24`

How does a simple pgp encryption of string work using openpgp.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually answer your question over suggesting another library, the fix is in changeing the syntax from

```
message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),
```

to

```
message: openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),
```

Then it should works since that method is not async (anymore?)

Here your example modified for symetric encryption (that's why I couldn't use jsencrypt as Nikola suggested:

```
 <script lang="JavaScript" src="openpgp.js"></script>
 <script lang="JavaScript">
    const options = {
        message : window.openpgp.message.fromText('Hello, World!'),     
        passwords : ['pw'],
        armor : false
    }

    window.openpgp.encrypt(options).then(ciphertext => {
        encrypted = ciphertext.message 
        return encrypted
    }).then(encrypted => {
        const options = {
            message : encrypted,   
            passwords : ['pw']                               
        }
        window.openpgp.decrypt(options).then(plaintext => {
            console.log(plaintext.data)
            alert(plaintext.data)
            return plaintext.data 
        })
    })       
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The library you're trying to use doesn't look that promissing for asymetric cryptography. 
If you're open for suggestion try using [this](http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/) one.

Here is example code :

```
<div class="container">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsencrypt/2.3.1/jsencrypt.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Call this code when the page is done loading.
        jQuery(function () {
            // Run a quick encryption/decryption when they click.
            jQuery('#testme').click(function () {
                // Encrypt with the public key...
                var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
                encrypt.setPublicKey($('#pubkey').val());
                var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt($('#input').val());
                console.log(encrypted);
                // Decrypt with the private key...
                var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
                decrypt.setPrivateKey($('#privkey').val());
                var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(encrypted);
                // Now a simple check to see if the round-trip worked.
                if (uncrypted == $('#input').val()) {
                    alert('It works!!!');
                }
                else {
                    alert('Something went wrong....');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <label for="privkey">Private Key</label><br/>
<textarea id="privkey" rows="15" cols="65">-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----</textarea><br/>
    <label for="pubkey">Public Key</label><br/>
<textarea id="pubkey" rows="15" cols="65">-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlOJu6TyygqxfWT7eLtGDwajtN
FOb9I5XRb6khyfD1Yt3YiCgQWMNW649887VGJiGr/L5i2osbl8C9+WJTeucF+S76
xFxdU6jE0NQ+Z+zEdhUTooNRaY5nZiu5PgDB0ED/ZKBUSLKL7eibMxZtMlUDHjm4
gwQco1KRMDSmXSMkDwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----</textarea><br/>
    <label for="input">Text to encrypt:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="input" name="input" type="text" rows=4 cols=70>This is a test!</textarea><br/>
    <input id="testme" type="button" value="Test Me!!!"/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am open to other libs as its just for my training. 

Do you the methods of this lib to create the keypairs inside the browser instead of using
openssl genrsa -out rsa_1024_priv.pem 1024 ?

Comment: this one works well. Fast and easy to play around. Thnaks

Comment: `encrypt.encrypt()` returns false for me